# Entity Framework foreign key that is not a primary key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, guid

I am having problems with my MSSQL database design.

I had 2 tables that looked like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tenants 
(
    tenantId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    tenantName VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE users 
(
    userId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    userName VARCHAR,
    tenantId INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (tenantId) REFERENCES tentants(tenantId)
)
```

I wanted to switch from only IDs to GUIDs for uniqueness and changed the tables.
I have read that GUIDs as primary keys are not recommended for performance reasons. So I kept the IDs:

```
CREATE TABLE tenants 
(
    tenantId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    tenantGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    tenantName VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE users 
(
    userId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    userGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    userName VARCHAR,
    tenantGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    FOREIGN KEY (tenantGuid) REFERENCES tentants(tenantGuid)
)
```

Now Entity Framework is going wild just dismissing all relationships because the guids are not part of the primary key.

On old posts I have read that this would be not supported. Is it still not supported?

How am I support to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Also sorry for the bad formatting, the editor doesn't respect my line breaks :/

soomon

Comment: finally you want GUID to be primary key?

Comment: For future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: **What** concrete RDBMS is this for?? `SQL` is just the query language - used by many RDBMS like `oracle`, `postgresql`, `sybase`, `db2`, `mysql`, or `sql-server` - you should **really** tell us what concrete RDBMS you're using

Comment: Thank you Andrew for the formatting! I am using MSSQL 2016 Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to switch from only IDs to GUIDs for uniqueness and changed the tables.

You don't really need to switch to GUIDs to ensure uniqueness.Your IDs will be guaranteed to be unique (whichever type they are, say integer) as long as they are set as your primary keys.

> I have read that GUIDs as primary keys are not recommended for performance reasons. So I kept the IDs
>
> `tenantGuid uniqueidentifier foreign key to tenants.tenantGuid`

Assuming you're talking about performance of 'joins' when using GUID as the key then keeping ID's as primary key will not make a difference since queries will be made on the GUID anyway.

> Now entity framework is going wild just dismissing all relationships because the guids are not part of the primary key.
>
> How am I support to solve this?

I believe you're better off not solving this and rather choosing either to go back to your previous database design which uses the integer ID. Or ultimately use GUID as your primary key (removing integer ID in the process).

Comment: I guess you are right. It's sad but seems to be the best option

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to us the unique identifier, you need to take note on the below two things

> Set the tenants.tenantGuid to UNIQUE KEY and also set the users.tenantGuid as the same data type

Modify the tables as below

```
CREATE TABLE tenants (
    tenantId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    tenantGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER UNIQUE,
    tenantName VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE users (
    userId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    userGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    userName VARCHAR,
    tenantGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    FOREIGN KEY (tenantGuid) REFERENCES tenants(tenantGuid)
)
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Setting "tenantGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER UNIQUE" does not work, and setting it to "tenantGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER UNIQUE KEY" generates errors in the DB project: "incorrect syntax near key", expecting '(' or SELECT...

Comment: I'm using MSSQL Server 2016 and the above query runs without any errors. You can try to create the UNIQUE KEY constraint like

> ALTER TABLE tenants ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_some_constraint_name UNIQUE(tenantGuid)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints

Comment: yes it runs on MSSQL Server but entity framework still does not like it because tenantGuid  is not part of the key on table tenants. The problem is with entity framework, not with MSSQL server :/